# Insufficient Privileges - Visualforce Page - Occurs as System Admin

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, permissions, activities, insufficient-privileges

UPDATE:  RESOLVED!  I heard back from Tier 3 support and they acknowledge a bug and said it was due to a user selecting "Feed-Based Layout" on the Create New Layout screen. Be careful with that option when using visualforce pages until they fix!  [image: Screen shot of feedbased layout]

I have a client using a managed package that includes a visualforce page to override tasks and events.  **All users** (including my System admin account) gets the:

> Insufficient Privileges - You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested.  Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.  For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors

I have googled and followed the suggestions of every post I could find to solve this issue.  Please look at the list below of the things I have tried and see if I overlooked a possible cause:

- Vender of managed package reviewed the issue and could not resolve
- Reviewed setup audit logs to see what changed around the time that the error started occuring
- Checked debug logs at finest level - "Success" (no help) :(
- Tested in a Sandbox refreshed a couple months ago with the same version of managed package and configuration - Sandbox works great
- Verified the controller and visualforce API version match
- Verified all profiles have access to the visualforce page (via VF security)
- Verified all profiles have access to the APEX controller
- Verified users have access to the objects (the task and event page loads fine when override is removed. The visualforce page does pull information from a custom object but that object is fully accessible.)
- Verified that the error occurs no matter what role in role hierarchy the user is in.
- Sharing settings for activities are set to "Controlled by Parent".  Users can access parent records without issue.
- A related permission set was modified around the time this occurred.  So, I brought over an older version of the permission set that works in a sandbox and the error persists.
- UPDATE: Forced recalculation of sharing settings on all objects.
- UPDATE: Verified licenses for managed packaged are properly allocated.
- UPDATE: Verified field level security on task/event and all related objects to the managed package.

I was able to get an event record to load without using the VF override but I haven't identified the difference.  I am still investigating that. **UPDATE:** Discovered that I get the error when the event or task is related to a specific object that is from the same managed package.

One other item I should note that may or may not be related.  A key user of this client was recently let go and their account was set inactive.  Around that same time the error began occurring. We have re-enabled their account.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:  Looks like this error ONLY occurs when it's related to one of the objects that is provided by the installed package.  But, as a system admin I have "modify all" for this object. And I can view the records for this object when I access them directly.

UPDATE 2: I am at a complete loss here.  This org does not have premier support.  I am considering re-installing the managed package but I am concerned about the implications of that.  (Of course I'll reach out to the vendor about doing this and also test in sandbox.)

UPDATE 3:  Got in touch with tier 1, waiting to be escalated.  In the meantime...  I was able to get the source code for the VF page from the managed package and create a VERY simplified version of the VF page.  I received the same error when the task/event was related to the managed package object.  Again, I and all other users can access any records from the managed package object but when the record is related to a task/event the VF page throws the "Insufficient Privileges" error.

Also, I was able to pull this fun error message.  Any thoughts?

Take a look:

```
EntityObject can not be initialized with null EntityInfo
system.security.NoAccessException: EntityObject can not be initialized with null EntityInfo
    at common.udd.object.EntityObjectImpl.<init>(EntityObjectImpl.java:122)
    at common.udd.object.EntityObject.<init>(EntityObject.java:124)
    at common.ownership.OwnedEntityObject.<init>(OwnedEntityObject.java:55)
    at core.customentity.BaseCustomDataTemplateObject.<init>(BaseCustomDataTemplateObject.java:35)
    at core.customentity.CustomEntityDataTemplateObject.<init>(CustomEntityDataTemplateObject.java:40)
    at core.customentity.CustomEntityDataTemplateUi.<init>(CustomEntityDataTemplateUi.java:34)
    at core.customentity.CustomEntityDataTemplateUi.<init>(CustomEntityDataTemplateUi.java:30)
    at core.customentity.CustomEntityDataTemplatePage.hook_init_entityUi(CustomEntityDataTemplatePage.java:50)
    at core.customentity.CustomEntityDataTemplatePage.hook_init_entityUi(CustomEntityDataTemplatePage.java:1)
    at common.entityfeed.ui.AbstractEntityFeedPage.hook_init_entityUi(AbstractEntityFeedPage.java:58)
    at common.page.GenericEntityPage.<init>(GenericEntityPage.java:827)
    at common.page.GenericEntityPage.<init>(GenericEntityPage.java:817)
    at common.entityfeed.ui.AbstractEntityFeedPage.<init>(AbstractEntityFeedPage.java:48)
    at core.customentity.CustomEntityDataTemplatePage.<init>(CustomEntityDataTemplatePage.java:45)
    at core.apexpages.components.ApexGenericPageComponent.getGenericEntityPage(ApexGenericPageComponent.java:139)
    at core.apexpages.components.ApexGenericPageComponent.getPageComponentizer(ApexGenericPageComponent.java:115)
    at core.apexpages.components.ApexGenericPageComponent.getComponentizer(ApexGenericPageComponent.java:243)
    at core.apexpages.components.ApexDetailComponent.beforeEncode(ApexDetailComponent.java:174)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil$3.visit(ApexComponentUtil.java:1498)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil$1.call(ApexComponentUtil.java:1038)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil$1.call(ApexComponentUtil.java:1)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil._visitComponents(ApexComponentUtil.java:1061)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil._visitChildrenOnce(ApexComponentUtil.java:1099)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil._processChildren(ApexComponentUtil.java:1085)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil.access$5(ApexComponentUtil.java:1079)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil$1.call(ApexComponentUtil.java:1042)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil$1.call(ApexComponentUtil.java:1)
    at core.apexpages.framework.context.VFContextServiceImpl.run(VFContextServiceImpl.java:2867)
    at core.apexpages.framework.context.VFContextServiceImpl.runWithComponentContext(VFContextServiceImpl.java:2748)
    at core.apexpages.framework.context.VFContextServiceImpl.runWithComponentContextIfDiff(VFContextServiceImpl.java:2704)
    at core.apexpages.framework.context.VFContextServiceImpl.runWithComponentContextIfDiff(VFContextServiceImpl.java:2699)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil._visitComponents(ApexComponentUtil.java:1063)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil._visitChildrenOnce(ApexComponentUtil.java:1099)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil._processChildren(ApexComponentUtil.java:1085)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil.access$5(ApexComponentUtil.java:1079)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil$1.call(ApexComponentUtil.java:1042)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil$1.call(ApexComponentUtil.java:1)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil._visitComponents(ApexComponentUtil.java:1061)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil._visitChildrenOnce(ApexComponentUtil.java:1099)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil._processChildren(ApexComponentUtil.java:1085)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil.access$5(ApexComponentUtil.java:1079)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil$1.call(ApexComponentUtil.java:1042)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil$1.call(ApexComponentUtil.java:1)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil._visitComponents(ApexComponentUtil.java:1061)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil.visitComponents(ApexComponentUtil.java:953)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.util.ApexComponentUtil.doBeforeEncode(ApexComponentUtil.java:1444)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.context.ApexPagesAjaxViewRoot.encodeAll(ApexPagesAjaxViewRoot.java:79)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:566)
    at core.apexpages.components.framework.context.ApexViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ApexViewHandlerImpl.java:251)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:106)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:178)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:109)
    at core.apexpages.framework.ApexPagesLifecycleImpl.phase(ApexPagesLifecycleImpl.java:164)
    at core.apexpages.framework.ApexPagesLifecycleImpl.render(ApexPagesLifecycleImpl.java:95)
    at visualforce.VisualforceServiceImpl$1.call(VisualforceServiceImpl.java:262)
    at visualforce.VisualforceServiceImpl$1.call(VisualforceServiceImpl.java:1)
    at core.apexpages.framework.context.VFContextServiceImpl.run(VFContextServiceImpl.java:2867)
    at core.apexpages.framework.context.VFContextServiceImpl.runWithComponentContext(VFContextServiceImpl.java:2803)
    at core.apexpages.framework.context.VFContextServiceImpl.runWithComponentContextIfDiff(VFContextServiceImpl.java:2704)
    at visualforce.VisualforceServiceImpl.invokePage(VisualforceServiceImpl.java:179)
    at core.apexpages.framework.ApexViewServlet.handlePage(ApexViewServlet.java:348)
    at common.request.servlet.BaseApplicationServlet.serviceInternal(BaseApplicationServlet.java:138)
    at common.request.servlet.BaseApplicationServlet.doService(BaseApplicationServlet.java:74)
    at common.request.servlet.ProtectedHttpServlet.service(ProtectedHttpServlet.java:36)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1439)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:522)
    at core.apexpages.framework.ApexViewFilter.doFilter(ApexViewFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:194)
    at core.apexpages.framework.ApexViewXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(ApexViewXMLFilter.java:23)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:281)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:379)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:507)
    at core.apexpages.framework.ApexViewFilter.doFilter(ApexViewFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at klein.filter.JettyStreamWriterAdaptorFilter.doFilter(JettyStreamWriterAdaptorFilter.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.cookie.CookieCatalogFilter.doFilter(CookieCatalogFilter.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at security.services.validator.VulnerabilityCheckFilter.doFilter(VulnerabilityCheckFilter.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.SeparateDomainRedirectFilter.doFilter(SeparateDomainRedirectFilter.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at core.dns.filter.CustomDomainMappingFilter.doFilter(CustomDomainMappingFilter.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at core.dns.filter.SiteRedirectMappingFilter.doFilter(SiteRedirectMappingFilter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at core.dns.filter.BandwidthMeterFilter.doFilter(BandwidthMeterFilter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.OrgDomainFilter.doFilter(OrgDomainFilter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.StatsOnlyFilter.doFilter(StatsOnlyFilter.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:290)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.gzip.CommonGzipFilterProxy.doFilter(CommonGzipFilterProxy.java:27)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.gzip.CommonGzipFilter.doFilter(CommonGzipFilter.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.BasePreGzipFilter.doFilter(BasePreGzipFilter.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.modifyparam.ModifiableParameterFilter.doFilter(ModifiableParameterFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at klein.filter.MultiPartFilter.doFilter(MultiPartFilter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at com.force.http.routing.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.InstanceRedirectFilter.doFilter(InstanceRedirectFilter.java:860)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.routing.CommonRemoteAddrFilter.doFilter(CommonRemoteAddrFilter.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.LegacyJSPFilter.doFilter(LegacyJSPFilter.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at routing.ios.IosRoutingFilter.doFilter(IosRoutingFilter.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at core.feeds.notification.tracking.ClickTrackingFilter.doFilter(ClickTrackingFilter.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at core.dns.filter.SitesRuntimeForwardingFilter.requestIsNotForSites(SitesRuntimeForwardingFilter.java:208)
    at core.dns.filter.SitesRuntimeForwardingFilter.doFilterInternal(SitesRuntimeForwardingFilter.java:487)
    at core.dns.filter.SitesRuntimeForwardingFilter.doFilter(SitesRuntimeForwardingFilter.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at core.dns.filter.SitesProxyCachingFilter.doFilter(SitesProxyCachingFilter.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at routing.filter.LoadBalancerFilter.doFilter(LoadBalancerFilter.java:80)
    at routing.loadbalancer.SfdcLoadBalancerFilter.doFilter(SfdcLoadBalancerFilter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at common.util.database.ZeroDowntimeSpinModeFilter.doFilter(ZeroDowntimeSpinModeFilter.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.orgdomain.OrgDomainLoadBalancerFilter.doFilter(OrgDomainLoadBalancerFilter.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.context.CommonStackableContextWatchingFilter.doFilter(CommonStackableContextWatchingFilter.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.context.CommonContextReleaseFilter.doFilter(CommonContextReleaseFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.SessionNeverEstablishedLogFilter.doFilter(SessionNeverEstablishedLogFilter.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at com.force.http.routing.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at com.force.http.routing.RoutingFilter.handleFilter(RoutingFilter.java:122)
    at com.force.http.routing.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.Immediate404Filter.doFilter(Immediate404Filter.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.ResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderFilter.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.logging.CommonAccessLogFilter.doFilter(CommonAccessLogFilter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.context.CommonRequestIdFilter.doFilter(CommonRequestIdFilter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.RegulatorWaitTestFilter.doFilter(RegulatorWaitTestFilter.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.RegulatorFilter.doFilter(RegulatorFilter.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at system.filter.RequestPathSecurityFilter.doFilter(RequestPathSecurityFilter.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.encoding.CommonRequestEncodingFilter.doFilter(CommonRequestEncodingFilter.java:86)
    at system.filter.RequestEncodingFilter.doFilter(RequestEncodingFilter.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RegexServletHandler.doScope(RegexServletHandler.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:967)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at klein.handler.SfdcJettytHandler.handle(SfdcJettytHandler.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1036)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Check field level security on all fields for the managed package, esp anything on task / event or the managed object that is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Gorav.  On your suggestion, I did that this morning.  I looked at the event/task object and every related object I could see that was connected to the managed package.  No luck.  All profiles, including system admin, continue to have the issue.

Comment: What are the org wide defaults on the object that is causing the issue?  If it's private, does changing it to public ro or rw does that help?  Make sure you won't expose data by making the change!

Comment: And test whether the issue happens on newly created managed object records as well as old ones.

Comment: Is this for an internal VF page, or on a site?

Comment: @gorav - OWD - Task/Event - Controlled By Parent, Managed package objects - Public Read/Write

Comment: @NickCook - Internal VF Page

Comment: Owd for one of the managed objects that is causing the issue?  I believe you indicate that the issue only occurs when task is connected to managed object record.  It's just a wild guess at this point, if modify all doesn't get you there then it has to be a licensing issue

Comment: @gorav - I tested against a brand new record for the managed package object.  Same issue.

Comment: As a note, I've found the 'Insufficient Privileges' can be a bit of a red herring.  It can be displayed when other errors occur, not just permission issues.  That's more likely to happen with a site, rather than an internal VF page though.  As an example, we had a VF page that referenced a controller variable that didn't exist.  This displayed the 'Insufficient Privileges' message, even though it was an exception being thrown.  That was on a site though, not an internal VF page.

Comment: You've left no stone unturned.  If this is a paid product I would double down on their support.  They have the ability to debug on their side, once you grant access, and can gey more info out of the debug log than you can since it's managed.  Or perhaps they can make some trivial update to the vf page and controller which would allow you to update to a new version instead of reinstall.  On a separate note, re the timing, given that summer just happened, seems like it might be related to that?  Do you have shared activities turned on or off?  Recall some summer16 action on those I beleive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: RESOLVED! I heard back from Tier 3 support and they acknowledge a bug and said it was due to a user selecting "Feed-Based Layout" on the Create New Layout screen. Be careful with that option when using visualforce pages until they fix!

[image: Screen shot of feed based layout checkbox]

Comment: Please find the Known issue link for the same below

KI : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eJZRAA2

Kindly subscribe to this Known issue to get notifications regarding the fixes.

Answer (score 5):

It looks your system admin profile may not have one of these permission:-

1. License to access that managed package.
2. Access to the visualforce page.
3. Access to the class the visualforce page calls.
4. Access to Task or Event object.

Comment: Number 2 and 3 is irrelevant. Number 1 is the correct answer.

Comment: I don't think 1 is valid.  I can access the objects/records and visualforce pages from the managed package in some cases but not others.

Comment: Number 4 is not valid either.  I can access all tasks and events.  No error when override on view is disabled.

Comment: What do you mean by 'In some cases but not others'?  Item 1 still looks like the most likely cause.

Comment: @NickCook - I agree.  I should be clearer.  I meant  to say only in cases where the task or event was related to the managed package record.  But that managed package record IS accessible when going to it directly.  Also, the VF override page is also an asset of the managed package and it functions properly  when the task/event is related to another object.  I'll check with vendor on licensing issue.

Comment: Is there any debug available for the managed package? I'd assume the controller of the VF page is throwing an exception or erroring out, which is causing a misleading 'Insufficient Privileges' message showing.  Is there any settings page for the managed package that might reference invalid data, such as the user that has left?  Are there any communities involved? Did the user that left have a license for the managed package?

Comment: @NickCook - great questions! - pursuing answers...

Comment: @Peter can you please review item 2 and 3 again and check if system admin has access to these items at profile level.

To me it looks like there is a button which opens a visualforce page, issue occurs as soon as you click on that button.

Comment: @maniaccoder - I have triple checked this.  All profiles have access.